# Approximation of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, approximation, interpolation

Let $f$ $\in$  C([0,1]), $f(0)=0$ and $\epsilon  > 0$. Prove there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $p(0)=f(0)=0$, $p´(0)=0$ and $||p-f|| < \epsilon$ . The norm is sup-norm

I Know that by Walsh theorem I can have the approximation condition and the interpolation but I don´t have the one about the derivative in $0$, also for another exercise in my class I know I can have an approximating polynomial with every $x^{4k} $ for $k=0, 1, 2, ...n$ where $n$ is the polynomial degree, but in this case I have the derivative condition but not $p(0)=0$.

Comment: If $f\ge 0$, approximate $\sqrt f$ sufficiently well by a polynomial $q$ with $q(0) = 0$. Then $p = q^2$ will approximate $f$ and $p(0) = p'(0) = 0$. If $f$ is not non-negative, decompose $f$ as $f = f_+ - f_-$ with $f_+ = \max\{0,f\}$ and $f_- = -\min\{0,f\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you already know how to show that there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $q'(0)=0$ and $\|q-f\|<\epsilon$.  Note that the constant term of $q$ is equal to $q(0)$, and must be smaller than $\epsilon$ since $f(0)=0$.  Now just remove the constant term from $q$ to get a polynomial $p$ such that $p(0)=0$ as well, and note that $\|p-q\|<\epsilon$.